# Passing additional form field from HTML to view in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I was following the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364948/additional-field-in-django-form), when I try to solve my solution but it doesn't work for me.

My problem:

I have Django Model object with 4 attributes.

Let's say I have something like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_at = models.IntegerField()
    second_at = models.IntegerField()
    third = models.TextField()
```

Then I have some view in which I would like to present the form with this object. But, I would like the user to only insert 2 of them, `user` and the `third` parameter need to be filled automatically; `user` from current user and `third` from another HTML element (in which row the form was filled).

```
class HomePage(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    model = MyModel
    fields = ('first', 'second')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Then I have in HTML created

```
    <form action="." method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="hidden" name="third" value="{{ item.third }}" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Does anyone know why this is not working? And or how should I make it work? Is there is a better way?

Marko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

The problem is, that when you use the `generic.CreateView` and set either fields, or form_class, then this class will only read those fields. Even if you add manually additional input field it will not be passed inside class.

To solve this problem I created form class with hidden field.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.OrderDetail
        fields = ('first', 'second', 'third')
        widgets = {
            'third' : forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

Then I use this form as normal inside view class

```
class HomePage(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    model = MyModel
    form_class = forms.MyForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Then add additional hidden field inside HTML file

```
<form action="." method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="hidden" name="third" value="someValue" />
        <button type="submit" name="_submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This way, you replace your hidden field that come with `form.as_p` with custom one.

***Note:*** You ***don't*** really replace field. If you inspect the code, you will see, that you will have 2 hidden fields, but only one with value. But because both are hidden, no one could add value to another, so the behaviour is the same as the field would be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

Create a custom form under a forms.py  and exclude the fields let's say

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model=Mymodel
          exclude = ['user','third']
```

and in your create view import the form recenlty created and the use it into the CreateView with **form_clas**

```
class HomePage(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'index.html'
    model = MyModel
    fields = ('first', 'second')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```